# Why is the keyof this object type number or string?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Given:

```
type EventDefinitions<TEventPayload extends object> = {
    [eventName: string]: TEventPayload;
  };

type X = keyof EventDefinitions<object>;
```

Why is the type of X here `number | string` ? I would expect it to be just string as I am explicitly stating that it will be a string aren't I?

Comment: Would recommend opening an issue for typescript for this if there is not one already.

Comment: @Catalyst I dont want to bother them if its not a bug..

Comment: Typescript is constantly evolving, I would be surprised if this is the long-term desired behavior. As you have pointed out, the type you made can only have string keys.

Comment: Okay I have opened a bug: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26974

Answer (score 0):

If an object can be indexed with any string, then it can also be indexed with any number since the number will be implicitly converted to a string.  I assume that's the rationale, though I wasn't able to find any documentation in a few quick web searches.

Comment: Hmm.. Maybe, but then how do I explicitly say that its going to be a string then?

Comment: Do you mean you want to allow indexing with strings but generate an error if someone tries to index an `EventDefinitions<T>` with a number?  It looks like there isn't a way to do that.  I can see how that would be useful to catch mistakes, just like static typing in general.  You could file a suggestion.